# Flutter "Generated Plugins" showed with git changes when there are no changes

Tags: android, flutter, git, dart, github

I am on a Flutter project and I have this 7 files that are related to generated plugins, which showed changes when there were no changes made on my Git. Does anyone have this issue before and have a solution? Much appreciated!

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGo1P.png)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b1KI.png)

- Tried *git config --global core.filemode false* but doesn't works

Comment: If Git says two files are different, they are in fact different. Your editor may or may not *show* them as different since editors will often hide certain differences (such as whitespace at ends of lines or LF-only vs CRLF line terminators). Meanwhile: never use `--global` with `core.filemode`. This is useless because *every repository has a local setting*. The local setting *should* describe *how your OS works* and if you change it for a special purpose, be sure you know what you are doing (i.e., lying to Git, and how that will affect Git).

Comment: You can use `git diff` (from the command line) to see what's actually different in the files: modes and/or special otherwise-invisible characters will show up.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Managed to get it fixed when pull latest from flutter.